# how to save a structure in gap

Tags: gap

Is there a way to save a structure to a file in GAP?
For example :

```
data:=rec();
data.Name:="random matrix";
data.Value:=RandomMat(3,4);
data.Rank:=2;
```

How would I save "data" to a file so it can be read from GAP at a future session?
and how would I read it back in.
(I don't want to save the entire workspace, just the records I want to use later).

Comment: This is not a question about Mathematics.

Comment: Use `LogTo(filename);`.

Comment: @Shaun that won't work. In real use "data" is a huge structure with large matrices..."LogTo" just logs the console output of whatever is printed out...

Comment: @unknown Some forum whose rules don't include: ”Don't ask about anything not directly related to math”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no dedicated functionality for saving a single object. Using `Print` (or `PrintTo` a file) should produce GAP-readable input, but you need to supply the assignment syntax yourself, and you will lose information caches inside objects, or use of compressed data types.

In your case, you could use

```
PrintTo("mydatafile","data:=",data,";\n");
```

so that `Read("mydatafile");` would give you an object in a new session.

Comment: Thanks, this will work but that seems to force "data" to be a global variable. So if I have a function with local variable "data" then Read("mydatafile") will not assign the record to the local variable.

Comment: If it must be a local variable, have a look at the documentation for `ReadAsFunction`, whioch allows you to assign return values to local variables.

Comment: ReadAsFunction does the job...thanks